Are very-occasional, very-high read latencies expected from an NVMe SSD under Linux/ext4?
Background context info:  I'm working on an application that streams multiple tracks of audio from an NVMe SSD, and I'm measuring the performance of the system to determine how much buffering I need to provide in order to avoid any audio-underruns caused by varying disk-read.
For simplicity, I'm running on an otherwise-idle, GUI-less, real-hardware 20-core Linux server, the filesystem is ext4, and I set my program to only read audio data via a single thread (in real-world use it would use multiple I/O threads, but the SSD behavior I see then is similar).  I have it set to read data from 1,536 96kHz audio files simultaneously, so the expected data-throughput is (3*96000*1536) = ~421 MB/sec, which on average the SSD and CPU handles just fine.  In my test harness, the audio data is simply discarded after it is read.
My question, however, is about read-latencies.  In particular, I notice that 99.99% of my read-requests (which are 128KB each) get handled in less than one millisecond, which is awesome.  However, a very small percentage of the reads take longer (on the order of some milliseconds), and very occasionally I get a really monstrous outlier that can take up to 200 milliseconds(!) to complete.
I instrumented my program to build up a histogram of measured read-latencies, and over the course of several hours it reported this:
Read latencies histogram:
  41358428 @ <1mS
      1328 @ 1-9 mS 
       440 @ 10-19 mS
       432 @ 20-29 mS
        33 @ 30-39 mS 
       109 @ 40-49 mS
        43 @ 50-59 mS 
        10 @ 60-69 mS 
         5 @ 70-79 mS  
         2 @ 80-89 mS  
         4 @ 90-99 mS  
         2 @ 100-109 mS
         5 @ 130-139 mS
         1 @ 140-149 mS
         3 @ 150-159 mS
         1 @ 170-179 mS
         2 @ 180-189 mS
         4 @ 190-199 mS
         1 @ 200-209 mS

My question is, is this sort of "long tail" behavior expected for a modern NVMe SSD drive, or does the presence of the very rare 100+mS latencies indicate a problem with my hardware or software?  I don't know whether I should accept this as a fact of life, increase my app's buffer sizes, and move on, or if I should try to figure out what is causing the long reads and fix it.
Updated per comments:  the SSD's model number is TS2TMTE662T2-G1, which I think means it is one of these.
Output from lsblk, for reference:
root@xxxxx:~# lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL
NAME         FSTYPE      LABEL MOUNTPOINT  SIZE MODEL
nvme0n1                                    1.9T TS2TMTE662T2-G1                         
|-nvme0n1p1  vfat                          512M 
|-nvme0n1p2  crypto_LUKS                     8G 
| `-rootfs_a ext4                            8G 
|-nvme0n1p3  crypto_LUKS                     8G 
| `-rootfs_b ext4              /             8G 
|-nvme0n1p4  ext4              /var/log      2G 
|-nvme0n1p5  ext4              /cfg        128M 
`-nvme0n1p6  ext4              /udata      1.8T 


Can not be answered - what SSD? SSD rely heavily on caching and other stuff and there are SERIOUS differences between models, among them for SUSTAINABLE data rate. You may hit into that. Without knowing the model - it is not even possible to check the data sheet.

Voting to close: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. - add the hardware details.

What SSD are you using? Does using XFS give the same results? Have you tried to disable pcie aspm? Does you program writes something to the disks, possibly using fsync?

I've updated my question to include model info.

I would test with a drive from another vendor.

With further exploration and testing I found that one common cause of intermittent high latencies is garbage collection by the SSD drive.
In particular, due to the way that NAND flash works, anytime the SSD firmware wants to write more data, it needs a fresh (all-zeroes) flash page to write the data to.  If it doesn't have one already available, it must do a rather time-consuming "erase" step on a block of flash in order to create one, before the I/O request can complete.  This behavior can result in very high latencies in that scenario, but it can be (mostly) avoided by doing running fstrim on the drive periodically (so that the drive doesn't run out of all-zeroes pages while in use).
Note that this behavior should only manifest itself if the drive is being written to as well as read from, and there are probably other sources for occasional high latencies as well, that I'm not aware of yet.
